# Best practice for text in html

Tags: html, seo

What html tag is used for text that is neither a heading `<h1>` nor a paragraph `<p>` ? The `<pre>` tag is not appropriate because I need to style the text with CSS. (So, the text is basically a non-important phrase.)

Example 1:
Price per product: $5

Example 2:
Add to Cart

What would be the best practice (or standard way) of dealing with this situation ? Can text be placed inside an `<aside>` tag without first surrounding it with `<h1>` or `<p>` ?

Comment: Actually you can style PRE tag using CSS. By the way the direct neutral alternative to **H1** or **P** is **DIV**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 1:** If you're feeling semantic, you can write it like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Price per product:</dt>
    <dd>$5</dd>
    <dt>Products in stock:</dt>
    <dd>12</dd>
</dl>
```

Otherwise, a span tag would be fine.

---

**Example 2:** Use an `<a />` or `<button />`

Answer (score 5):

I think that the span tag should be right for that porposes.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4)

> The DIV and SPAN elements, in conjunction with the id and class
>   attributes, offer a generic mechanism for adding structure to
>   documents. These elements define content to be inline (SPAN) or
>   block-level (DIV) but impose no other presentational idioms on the
>   content. Thus, authors may use these elements in conjunction with
>   style sheets, the lang attribute, etc., to tailor HTML to their own
>   needs and tastes.
>
> Suppose, for example, that we wanted to generate an HTML document
>   based on a database of client information. Since HTML does not include
>   elements that identify objects such as "client", "telephone number",
>   "email address", etc., we use DIV and SPAN to achieve the desired
>   structural and presentational effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<span>`. 
For your info, you can style `<pre>` using css.

```
<style>
pre{
//style here
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the `span` tag, a catch-all inline which is great for DOM selectors, JS/CSS, and general organization.  Though for what it's worth, the `h1` through `h3` tags get used for non-headers all the time and nobody minds too much.

Edit: Except, it turns out, folks with screen-readers.  It might be a good idea not to use headers this way after all.

Comment: hm, was under the impression that screenreaders did OK with them. guess I should look into it.

Comment: as I understand it, screen readers will, on request, read out all the headers on the page, so that the user quickly gets an idea of all of the content. (Like the auditory equivalent of a scan.) If you’ve marked up non-headers as headers, then they’ll get read out too, which would at best be annoying, and at worst confusing. I’ve never used a screen reader myself though, so pinch of salt and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the tags which describe what the text is. If you have a paragraph of text, use `<p>`. If you have a quotation use `<blockquote>`.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) for a list of the tags and what they describe.

Comment: So what do I use for "Add to Cart" ?